# regex lookbehind skip multiline comments

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to convert an application from PHP 4 to PHP 7 application. In particular I have to fix the problem in which the variables coming from HTML forms are not explicitly defined in the destination page caught by a POST or REQUEST. I'm going to do it manually but first I need to find them.

To do so I wanted to write a regular expression that checks if a PHP variable has been previously defined in the page. I managed to do it with backreferences and unrestricted lookbehind (some language allow it) but I cannot manage multiline comments /*...*/ . I need to skip them in the lookbehind search.
I was able skip on line type comment //... and ingore the content of the comments but not to go beyond it skipping completely: a variable declaration before /*..*/ is not matched by the regex.

I'm using PowerGrep 4 as regex engine.

Here my incomplete regex, it uses backreference and nested lookbehinds:

```
(?<!(?<!//.*)\1[\s]*\=[\s]*.*;[^\*]*[^/]*)(\$\b(?:[^\_])[a-zA-Z-_\d]+\b)(?![\s]*[\=]{1}[^\=])
```

EXAMPLE: given the code:

```
blabla $var  /*  blabla /  *  $var = 2 * / blabla */   $var
```

it should match $var twice before and after the comment ignoring the definition inside the comment.

Also consider the following:

```
blabla $var  blabla  $var = 2  /*  blabla /  *  $var  * / blabla */   $var
```

should match only the first $var, because only the first occurrence of $var is not preceded by a variable definition.

Currently I can create a regex that can either go back to check for an assignment matching even if it is inside multiline comments (WRONG) or ignore assignment inside comments but not being able detect any assignment BEFORE the multiline comment which is wrong again.

I cannot find a way to get both the above behaviour at the same time.

Does anyone have a solution or other ideas for my problem?

Comment: Some input/expected output maybe...?